# Onclick events for button

Tags: html, onclick

I have two buttons, save button and delete button. I need to add onclick event to both of the button. The onclick event function for delete button is working but I don't know how to onclick event to my save button.

This is my code.

```
<div class="form-group last">
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
    <input class="btn btn-info" id="savebutton" type="submit" name="save"  value="Update" > 
    <input class="btn btn-default" id="delete" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');"> 
</div>
```

What I want to do is when I click the save button, the record will be save into database and something alert box will display and if I click 'OK', it will go back to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not working for you or what exactly you are looking for but it should be the same way as you did for delete. Check the snippet :)

```js
function update(){
//databases work to save
alert("saved");
   //address to the page where to want to redirect
   location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group last">
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
    <input class="btn btn-info" id="savebutton" type="submit" name="save"  value="Update" onclick="update();"> 
    <input class="btn btn-default" id="delete" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');"> 
</div>
```

Comment: I know this can function, but what I need is when I click OK on the alert box it will go to another page

Comment: @user1120 doesn't work for you? after you click the ok button in alert box, the page should navigate to other page.

Comment: Can this `location.href = "www.yoursite.com";` direct to php?